# Javascript: Tilde is shown as hyphen

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(this)[0].nextSibling.data = 'Less than ~10 k';
```

This is the code I wrote in Javascript, but in the page it is shown as:

```
Less than -10 k
```

How to make it look like this:

```
Less than ~10 k
```

Inspection of the DOM selection shows correctly, but in the page it is wrong again.

Comment: Sounds like a font issue if the inspector shows it right. Are you using a custom font for this?

Comment: Does `$(this)[0].nextSibling.data = 'Less than \u007E10k';` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`$(this)[0].nextSibling.data = 'Less than \u007E10k';`

Comment: Absolutely same. Seems like font issue. Thanks guys!